# convert MMTPMsg structure from c++ to c#

Tags: c#, c++

I need use libmmtp.dll for communicate with mmtp protocol by server.
i use c# for call dll methode and one of the must complex structure of this lib is MMTPMsg

```
#ifndef _LIBPGA_H
# define _LIBPGA_H

# ifndef _UNUSED_
#   ifdef __GNUC__
#     define _UNUSED_ __attribute__ ((__unused__))
#   else
#     define _UNUSED_
#   endif
# endif
;
  static char const* LibPga_h_Rev _UNUSED_="@(#) $Name: LIV_MMTP_SDK_V2_15_00 $ $Header: /cvs/DTM/LIB/libpga/libpga.h,v 1.86 2004/10/22 10:45:40 fred Exp $";

# if defined(_LIBPGA_COMPILATION_) && defined(_USRDLL)
#   define ExportApi __declspec(dllexport)
#   define ExportClass __declspec(dllexport)
# else
#   define ExportApi extern
#   define ExportClass
# endif

# if !defined(BOOL) && !defined(BOOL_DEF)
    typedef int BOOL;
#   define BOOL BOOL
# endif

# ifndef FALSE
#   define FALSE 0
# endif

# ifndef TRUE
#   define TRUE 1
# endif

# include <sys/types.h>
# include <sys/timeb.h>
# ifdef UNIX
#   include <netinet/in.h>
# endif

# ifndef _TICKS
#   define _TICKS
#   ifdef NT
      typedef __int64 Ticks;
#   else
      typedef long long Ticks;
#   endif
#   define UPPER_LONG_LONG ((Ticks)~0)
# endif

# ifndef _LLONG
#   define _LLONG
#   ifdef NT
      typedef signed __int64 llong;
      typedef unsigned __int64 ullong;
#   else
      typedef signed long long llong;
      typedef unsigned long long ullong;
#   endif
# endif

# ifdef NT
    typedef unsigned int in_addr_t;
# endif

# ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C"
    {
# endif

# ifndef STX
#   define STX 2
# endif
# ifndef ETX
#   define ETX 3
# endif

# define MMTP_IN  0
# define MMTP_OUT 1

  // Type of protocol messages.
# define MSG_EMPTY   0
# define CONX_REQ   10
# define CONX_ACK   11
# define CONX_NACK  12
# define DCNX_REQ   13
# define DCNX_ACK   14
# define DSPTCH_MSG 15
# define START_REQ  20
# define START_ACK  21
# define START_NACK 22
# define DATA_MSG   23
# define SYNC_REQ   24
# define SYNC_ACK   25
# define ERR_IND    90
# define SRVC_MSG   93

# define CONX_REQ_STR   "10"
# define CONX_ACK_STR   "11"
# define CONX_NACK_STR  "12"
# define DCNX_REQ_STR   "13"
# define DCNX_ACK_STR   "14"
# define DSPTCH_MSG_STR "15"
# define START_REQ_STR  "20"
# define START_ACK_STR  "21"
# define START_NACK_STR "22"
# define DATA_MSG_STR   "23"
# define SYNC_REQ_STR   "24"
# define SYNC_ACK_STR   "25"
# define ERR_IND_STR    "90"
# define SRVC_MSG_STR   "93"

  // MMTP options index.
  typedef enum
  {
    MMTPOptCrypt=0,                       // 0 : Cryptage.
    MMTPOptCheckSeqNb,                    // 1 : Vérification du numéro de séquence.
    MMTPOptCheckCrypt,                    // 2 : Vérification de la validité du décryptage.
    MMTPOptCompression,                   // 3 : Compression des messages.
    // -------------------
    MMTP_MAX_OPT
  } MMTPCnxOption;

  // MMTP connection nack reason.
  typedef enum
  {
    MMTPCnxNckRsn_NoAnswer=-2,            // Pas d'envoi de réponse (pour MmtpBaseSession).
    MMTPCnxNckRsn_SendError=-1,           // Envoi d'une erreur OutOfContext (pour MmtpBaseSession).
    MMTPCnxNckRsn_Ok=0,                   // 0 : Connexion acceptée (pour MmtpBaseSession).
    MMTPCnxNckRsn_InvalidMember,          // 1 : Abonné invalide.
    MMTPCnxNckRsn_HubNotReady,            // 2 : Programme pas prêt.
    MMTPCnxNckRsn_UnknownMember,          // 3 : Membre (abonné) inconnu.
    MMTPCnxNckRsn_LastCnxTooRecent,       // 4 : Dernière connexion trop récente.
    MMTPCnxNckRsn_InvalidVersion,         // 5 : Versions de librairies incompatibles.
    MMTPCnxNckRsn_InvalidOptions,         // 6 : Options de connexion invalides.
    MMTPCnxNckRsn_TooManyCnx              // 7 : Trop de connexions simultanées.
  } MMTPCnxNckRsn;

  // MMTP disconnection reason
  typedef enum
  {
    MMTPDcnxRsn_NoAnswer=-2,              // Pas d'envoi de réponse (pour MmtpBaseSession).
    MMTPDcnxRsn_Normal=1,                 //  1 : Déconnexion normale.
    MMTPDcnxRsn_AskedByHub,               //  2 : Déconnexion demandée par lr programme.
    MMTPDcnxRsn_Abnormal,                 //  3 : Déconnexion anormale.
    MMTPDcnxRsn_SessionBroken,            //  4 : Session interrompue.
    MMTPDcnxRsn_InvalidStartAck,          //  5 : Déconnexion due à un Start-Ack invalide.
    MMTPDcnxRsn_LastMsgSent,              //  6 : Déconnexion due à l'envoi du dernier message.
    MMTPDcnxRsn_InvalidKey,               //  7 : Clé de cryptage invalide.
    MMTPDcnxRsn_InvalidAdminData,         //  8 : Données administratives invalides.
    MMTPDcnxRsn_AclViolation,             //  9 : ???
    MMTPDcnxRsn_EncryptionUnavailable=10, // 10 : Cryptage indisponible.
    MMTPDcnxRsn_Last=99
  } MMTPDcnxRsn;

  // MMTP start nack reason
  typedef enum
  {
    MMTPStrtNckRsn_NoAnswer=-2,           // Pas d'envoi de réponse (pour MmtpBaseSession).
    MMTPStrtNckRsn_SendError=-1,          // Envoi d'une erreur OutOfContext (pour MmtpBaseSession).
    MMTPStrtNckRsn_Ok=0,                  // 0 : Start-req accepté (pour MmtpBaseSession).
    MMTPStrtNckRsn_StartReqInProgress,    // 1 : Déjà un start-req en cours.
    MMTPStrtNckRsn_NoHubCnx,              // 2 : Connexion avec programme distant pas établie.
    MMTPStrtNckRsn_MsgIdNotFound          // 3 : Message demandé pas trouvé.
  } MMTPStrtNckRsn;

  // MMTP Err-Ind error
  typedef enum
  {
    MMTPErrIndErr_MsgLost=1,              // 1 : Message perdu (trou dans les numéros de séquence).
    MMTPErrIndErr_MsgDuplicate,           // 2 : Message dupliqués (numéro de séquence déjà reçu).
    MMTPErrIndErr_InvalidField,           // 3 : Champ invalide.
    MMTPErrIndErr_OutOfContext,           // 4 : Message hors de son contexte.
    MMTPErrIndErr_InvalidMsg,             // 5 : Message invalide.
    MMTPErrIndErr_AclViolation=9,         // 9 : ???
    MMTPErrInd_Last=99
  } MMTPErrIndErr;

  // Admin data types.
# define NO_ADMIN_DATA      0
# define ADMIN_DATA_UNKNOWN 1
# define ADMIN_DATA_E1      2
# define ADMIN_DATA_RR      3
# define ADMIN_DATA_E0      4
# define ADMIN_DATA_A1      5
# define ADMIN_DATA_A2      6
# define ADMIN_DATA_M0      7
# define ADMIN_DATA_G0      8

  // Size of protocol message fields.
# define FIELD_SIZE_SEQNB             8
# define FIELD_SIZE_SUBS_ID          11
# define FIELD_SIZE_VERSION           4
# define FIELD_SIZE_OPTIONS          16
# define FIELD_SIZE_AUTH_DATA         8
# define FIELD_SIZE_REASON            2
# define FIELD_SIZE_LENGTH            4
# define FIELD_SIZE_TYPE              2
# define FIELD_SIZE_ADMIN_TYPE        2
# define FIELD_SIZE_ERROR             2
# define FIELD_SIZE_ADMIN           256
# define FIELD_SIZE_DATA           9500
# define FIELD_SIZE_SERVICE           4
# define FIELD_SIZE_TIME             12
# define FIELD_SIZE_MSGID            24
# define FIELD_SIZE_FILLER_E0         5
# define FIELD_SIZE_FILLER_E1         8
# define FIELD_SIZE_FILLER_A1        11
# define FIELD_SIZE_FILLER_A2         5
# define FIELD_SIZE_FILLER_M0        41
# define FIELD_SIZE_FILLER_G0        29
# define FIELD_SIZE_TIMEOUT           6
# define FIELD_SIZE_ROUTE_DATA       11
# define FIELD_SIZE_MEMBER_ID         8
# define FIELD_SIZE_DOMAIN            1
# define FIELD_SIZE_IPADDR           10
# define FIELD_SIZE_PORT              5
# define FIELD_SIZE_FREE_SESSIONS     2
# define FIELD_SIZE_SERVER_ID        10
# define FIELD_SIZE_SERVER_DATA      32
# define FIELD_SIZE_SUBS_SEQ          8
# define FIELD_SIZE_SERV_TIME         6
# define FIELD_SIZE_NBHOP             1
# define FIELD_SIZE_CLASSID           4
# define FIELD_SIZE_ETT             128
# define FIELD_SIZE_IV                8
# define FIELD_SIZE_CONX_ACK_FILLER 100
# define FIELD_SIZE_ERROR_BODY      (FIELD_SIZE_DATA+FIELD_SIZE_ADMIN+24)

  // E0-type administrative data.
  typedef struct
  {
    char MsgId[FIELD_SIZE_MSGID+1];
    char SendTime[FIELD_SIZE_TIME+1];
    char ReceiptTime[FIELD_SIZE_TIME+1];
    char DeliveryTimeOut[FIELD_SIZE_TIMEOUT+1];
    char RouteData[FIELD_SIZE_ROUTE_DATA+1];
    char Filler[FIELD_SIZE_FILLER_E0+1];
  } MMTPAdminDataE0;

  // E1-type administrative data.
  typedef struct
  {
    char MsgId[FIELD_SIZE_MSGID+1];
    char SendTime[FIELD_SIZE_TIME+1];
    char ReceiptTime[FIELD_SIZE_TIME+1];
    char DeliveryTimeOut[FIELD_SIZE_TIMEOUT+1];
    char Filler[FIELD_SIZE_FILLER_E1+1];
  } MMTPAdminDataE1;

  // A1-type administrative data.
  typedef struct
  {
    char MsgId[FIELD_SIZE_MSGID+1];
    char SendTime[FIELD_SIZE_TIME+1];
    char ReceiptTime[FIELD_SIZE_TIME+1];
    char DeliveryTimeOut[FIELD_SIZE_TIMEOUT+1];
    char ReceiveTime[FIELD_SIZE_TIME+1];
    char SubsId[FIELD_SIZE_SUBS_ID+1];
    char MemberId[FIELD_SIZE_MEMBER_ID+1];
    char Domain[FIELD_SIZE_DOMAIN+1];
    char Dest[FIELD_SIZE_SUBS_ID+1];
    unsigned int  SubsSeq;
    unsigned int  ServTime;
    char ClassId[FIELD_SIZE_CLASSID+1];
    char Filler[FIELD_SIZE_FILLER_A1+1];
  } MMTPAdminDataA1;

  // A2-type administrative data.
  typedef struct
  {
    char MsgId[FIELD_SIZE_MSGID+1];
    char SendTime[FIELD_SIZE_TIME+1];
    char ReceiptTime[FIELD_SIZE_TIME+1];
    char DeliveryTimeOut[FIELD_SIZE_TIMEOUT+1];
    char ReceiveTime[FIELD_SIZE_TIME+1];
    char OnSubscriber[FIELD_SIZE_SUBS_ID+1];
    char OnMember[FIELD_SIZE_MEMBER_ID+1];
    char OnMsgId[FIELD_SIZE_MSGID+1];
    char Domain[FIELD_SIZE_DOMAIN+1];
    char Dest[FIELD_SIZE_SUBS_ID+1];
    char Filler[FIELD_SIZE_FILLER_A2+1];
  } MMTPAdminDataA2;

  typedef struct
  {
    char MsgId[FIELD_SIZE_MSGID+1];
    char SendTime[FIELD_SIZE_TIME+1];
    char ReceiptTime[FIELD_SIZE_TIME+1];
    char DeliveryTimeOut[FIELD_SIZE_TIMEOUT+1];
    char RouteData[FIELD_SIZE_ROUTE_DATA+1];
    char OnMember[FIELD_SIZE_MEMBER_ID+1];
    char Domain[FIELD_SIZE_DOMAIN+1];
    char Dest[FIELD_SIZE_SUBS_ID+1];
    char Filler[FIELD_SIZE_FILLER_M0+1];
  } MMTPAdminDataM0;

  // Generic administrative data.
  typedef struct
  {
    char MsgId[FIELD_SIZE_MSGID+1];
    char SendTime[FIELD_SIZE_TIME+1];
    char ReceiptTime[FIELD_SIZE_TIME+1];
  } MMTPAdminGeneric;

  typedef struct
  {
    char MsgId[FIELD_SIZE_MSGID+1];
    char SendTime[FIELD_SIZE_TIME+1];
    char ReceiptTime[FIELD_SIZE_TIME+1];
    char OnSubscriber[FIELD_SIZE_SUBS_ID+1];
    char OnMember[FIELD_SIZE_MEMBER_ID+1];
    char Domain[FIELD_SIZE_DOMAIN+1];
    char ClassId[FIELD_SIZE_CLASSID+1];
    char Dest[FIELD_SIZE_SUBS_ID+1];
    char NbHop[FIELD_SIZE_NBHOP+1];
    char ReceiveTime[FIELD_SIZE_TIME+1];
    char Filler[FIELD_SIZE_FILLER_G0+1];
    int EttType;
    int EttSize;
    union
    {
      MMTPAdminDataA1 A1;
      MMTPAdminDataA2 A2;
      MMTPAdminDataE0 E0;
      MMTPAdminDataE1 E1;
      MMTPAdminDataM0 M0;
      char Unknown[FIELD_SIZE_ETT];
    } Ett;
  } MMTPAdminDataG0;

  // RR-type administrative data.
# define FIELD_SIZE_RR_SPFID 8
# define FIELD_SIZE_RR_TYPE_TD 2
  typedef struct
  {
    long RelativeNumber;
    long Timestamp;
    unsigned short TD;
    char SpfId[FIELD_SIZE_RR_SPFID+1];
    char TypeTD[FIELD_SIZE_RR_TYPE_TD+1];
  } MMTPAdminDataRR;

  // Administrative data.
  typedef struct
  {
    int Type;
    int Size;
    union
    {
      MMTPAdminDataA1 A1;
      MMTPAdminDataA2 A2;
      MMTPAdminDataE0 E0;
      MMTPAdminDataE1 E1;
      MMTPAdminDataG0 G0;
      MMTPAdminDataM0 M0;
      MMTPAdminDataRR RR;
      MMTPAdminGeneric Generic;
    } Data;
    char Unknown[FIELD_SIZE_ADMIN];
  } MMTPAdminData;
# define FIELD_RECEIPT_TIME_POS (FIELD_SIZE_ADMIN_TYPE+FIELD_SIZE_MSGID+FIELD_SIZE_TIME)

  // Size of administrative data.
# define ADMIN_A1_SIZE (FIELD_SIZE_ADMIN_TYPE+FIELD_SIZE_MSGID+FIELD_SIZE_TIME*3+FIELD_SIZE_TIMEOUT+FIELD_SIZE_MEMBER_ID+FIELD_SIZE_DOMAIN+FIELD_SIZE_SUBS_ID*2+FIELD_SIZE_SUBS_SEQ+FIELD_SIZE_SERV_TIME+FIELD_SIZE_CLASSID+FIELD_SIZE_FILLER_A1)
# define ADMIN_A2_SIZE (FIELD_SIZE_ADMIN_TYPE+FIELD_SIZE_MSGID*2+FIELD_SIZE_TIME*3+FIELD_SIZE_TIMEOUT+FIELD_SIZE_SUBS_ID*2+FIELD_SIZE_DOMAIN+FIELD_SIZE_MEMBER_ID+FIELD_SIZE_FILLER_A2)
# define ADMIN_E0_SIZE (FIELD_SIZE_ADMIN_TYPE+FIELD_SIZE_MSGID+FIELD_SIZE_TIME*2+FIELD_SIZE_TIMEOUT+FIELD_SIZE_ROUTE_DATA+FIELD_SIZE_FILLER_E0)
# define ADMIN_E1_SIZE (FIELD_SIZE_ADMIN_TYPE+FIELD_SIZE_MSGID+FIELD_SIZE_TIME*2+FIELD_SIZE_TIMEOUT+FIELD_SIZE_FILLER_E1)
# define ADMIN_G0_SIZE (FIELD_SIZE_ADMIN_TYPE+FIELD_SIZE_MSGID+FIELD_SIZE_TIME*3+FIELD_SIZE_SUBS_ID*2+FIELD_SIZE_MEMBER_ID+FIELD_SIZE_DOMAIN+FIELD_SIZE_CLASSID+FIELD_SIZE_NBHOP+FIELD_SIZE_FILLER_G0+FIELD_SIZE_ETT)
# define ADMIN_M0_SIZE (FIELD_SIZE_ADMIN_TYPE+FIELD_SIZE_MSGID+FIELD_SIZE_TIME*2+FIELD_SIZE_TIMEOUT+FIELD_SIZE_ROUTE_DATA+FIELD_SIZE_MEMBER_ID+FIELD_SIZE_DOMAIN+FIELD_SIZE_SUBS_ID+FIELD_SIZE_FILLER_M0)
# define ADMIN_RR_SIZE (FIELD_SIZE_ADMIN_TYPE+sizeof(long)*2+sizeof(short)+FIELD_SIZE_RR_SPFID+FIELD_SIZE_RR_TYPE_TD)

  // Contents of CONX-REQ message.
  typedef struct
  {
    char SubsId[FIELD_SIZE_SUBS_ID+1];
    int Level;
    char Options[FIELD_SIZE_OPTIONS+1];
    char AuthData[FIELD_SIZE_AUTH_DATA+1];
  } MMTPConxReq;

  // Contents of CONX-ACK message.
  typedef struct
  {
    char Options[FIELD_SIZE_OPTIONS+1];
  } MMTPConxAck;

  // Contents of CONX-NACK message.
  typedef struct
  {
    MMTPCnxNckRsn Reason;
  } MMTPConxNack;

  // Contents of START-REQ message.
  typedef struct
  {
    char MsgId[FIELD_SIZE_MSGID+1];
  } MMTPStartReq;

  // Contents of START-ACK message.
  typedef struct
  {
    int SeqNb;
    char MsgId[FIELD_SIZE_MSGID+1];
  } MMTPStartAck;

  // Contents of START-NACK message.
  typedef struct
  {
    MMTPStrtNckRsn Reason;
    char MsgId[FIELD_SIZE_MSGID+1];
  } MMTPStartNack;

  // Contents of DATA-MSG message.
  typedef struct
  {
    int SeqNb;
    int DataSize;
    MMTPAdminData AD;
    char Data[FIELD_SIZE_DATA+1];
  } MMTPDataMsg;

  // Contents of SYNC-ACK message.
  typedef struct
  {
    int SeqNb;
    char MsgId[FIELD_SIZE_MSGID+1];
  } MMTPSyncAck;

  // Contents of DCNX-REQ.
  typedef struct
  {
    MMTPDcnxRsn Reason;
    int SeqNb;
  } MMTPDcnxReq;

  // Contents of DCNX-ACK.
  typedef struct
  {
    int SeqNb;
  } MMTPDcnxAck;

  // Contents of ERR-IND.
  typedef struct
  {
    MMTPErrIndErr Error;
    int SubError;
    int SeqNb;
    int Length;
    char Body[FIELD_SIZE_ERROR_BODY+1];
  } MMTPErrInd;

  // Contents of SRVC-MSG
  typedef struct
  {
    char Type[FIELD_SIZE_SERVICE+1];
    int Size;
    char Data[FIELD_SIZE_DATA+1];
  } MMTPSrvcMsg;

  // Contents of DSPTCH-MSG.
  typedef struct
  {
    char ServerId[FIELD_SIZE_SERVER_ID+1];
    char ServerData[FIELD_SIZE_SERVER_DATA+1];
    in_addr_t IpAddr;
    unsigned short Port;
    int FreeSessions;
  } MMTPDsptchMsg;

  // Contents of RCNX-REQ.
  typedef struct
  {
    in_addr_t IpAddr;
    int Port;
    char SubsId[FIELD_SIZE_SUBS_ID+1];
    char Options[FIELD_SIZE_OPTIONS+1];
    char AuthData[FIELD_SIZE_AUTH_DATA+1];
  } MMTPRcnxReq;

  typedef struct
  {
    long Length;
    short Type;
    union
    {
      MMTPConxReq ConxReq;
      MMTPConxAck ConxAck;
      MMTPConxNack ConxNack;
      MMTPErrInd ErrInd;
      MMTPDcnxReq DcnxReq;
      MMTPDcnxAck DcnxAck;
      MMTPDataMsg DataMsg;
      MMTPSyncAck SyncAck;
      MMTPStartReq StartReq;
      MMTPStartAck StartAck;
      MMTPStartNack StartNack;
      MMTPSrvcMsg SrvcMsg;
      MMTPDsptchMsg DsptchMsg;
      MMTPRcnxReq RcnxReq;
    } Data;
    Ticks TimeStamp;
  } MMTPMsg;

  typedef void* MMTPSESSION;
  typedef void* MMTPLPL;
# define MMTPLPL_DEFAULT ((void*)~0)

  // MMTP options which can be set by the MMTPSetOption function.
  typedef enum
  {
    MMTPOption_CheckAliveTimeout,
    MMTPOption_WriteTimeout,
    MMTPOption_AutoGetTicks,
    MMTPOption_NoDelay,
    MMTPOption_DumpGap,
    MMTPOption_Progress,
    MMTPOption_SendHeartBeat,
    MMTPOption_ZeroSeqNbAllowed,
    MMTPOption_LogDataMsg,
    MMTPOption_CompressionLevel,
    MMTPOption_AutoFlush,
    MMTPOption_SndBufferSize,
    MMTPOption_RcvBufferSize
  } MMTPOption;                    
# define MMTP_NO_CHECK_ALIVE 0
# define MMTP_MIN_CHECK_ALIVE_TIMEOUT 10
# define MMTP_MAX_CHECK_ALIVE_TIMEOUT 60*60*2
# define MMTP_INFINITE_WRITE_DELAY -1
# define MMTP_AUTO_GET_TICKS_ENABLED  1
# define MMTP_AUTO_GET_TICKS_DISABLED 0
# define MMTP_SEND_HEARTBEAT_ENABLED  1
# define MMTP_SEND_HEARTBEAT_DISABLED 0
# define MMTP_AUTO_FLUSH_ENABLED  1
# define MMTP_AUTO_FLUSH_DISABLED 0
# define MMTP_NO_DELAY_ENABLED  1
# define MMTP_NO_DELAY_DISABLED 0
# define MMTP_ZERO_SEQNB_ENABLED  1
# define MMTP_ZERO_SEQNB_DISABLED 0
# define MMTP_LOG_DATAMSG_ENABLED  1
# define MMTP_LOG_DATAMSG_DISABLED 0
# define MMTP_NO_WRITE_DELAY 0
# define MMTP_DEF_DUMP_GAP 300       // En secondes
# define MMTP_MIN_DUMP_GAP 1         // En secondes
# define MMTP_MAX_DUMP_GAP 7200      // En secondes
# define MMTP_DEF_SOCKET_BUFFER_SIZE (20*1024)
# define MMTP_MIN_SOCKET_BUFFER_SIZE (1024)
# define MMTP_MAX_SOCKET_BUFFER_SIZE (10*1024*1024)

  // Modes disponibles pour la fonction MMTPAddInput();
  typedef enum
  {
    MmtpInput_Read=0,
    MmtpInput_Write,
    MmtpInput_Error
  } MmtpInputMode;

  typedef enum
  {
    //  0 : No error
    MMTP_OK=0,
    //  1 : Logical connection not established.
    MMTP_NOT_CONNECTED,
    //  2 : Invalid IP address.
    MMTP_INVALID_ADDRESS,
    //  3 : Physical connection lost.
    MMTP_CNX_LOST,
    //  4 : No message received.
    MMTP_NO_MESSAGE,
    //  5 : Invalid argument.
    MMTP_INVALID_ARG,
    //  6 : Session open in server mode and the requested function is
    //      reserved for sessions open in client mode.
    MMTP_CLIENT_FCT,
    //  7 : Session open in client mode and the requested function is
    //      reserved for sessions open in server mode.
    MMTP_SERVER_FCT,
    //  8 : Invalid session.
    MMTP_INVALID_SESSION,
    //  9 : A message of the same type is still awaiting acceptance.
    MMTP_ALREADY_IN_PROGRESS,
    // 10 : Logical connection already established.
    MMTP_ALREADY_CONNECTED,
    // 11 : Library already initialized.
    MMTP_ALREADY_INITIALIZED,
    // 12 : Library not initialized.
    MMTP_NOT_INITIALIZED,
    // 13 : Encryption/decryption error.
    MMTP_CRYPT_ERROR,
    // 14 : Unable to open socket.
    MMTP_CANNOT_INIT_SOCKET,              // UNUSED
    // 15 : Insufficient memory.
    MMTP_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY,
    // 16 : Maximum number of sessions open.
    MMTP_TOO_MUCH_SESSIONS,
    // 17 : Impossible to open the protocol transfer log file.
    MMTP_CANNOT_OPEN_LOGFILE,
    // 18 : Protocol transfer log file not open.
    MMTP_LOGFILE_NOT_OPENED,
    // 19 : Socket full.
    MMTP_SOCKET_FULL,
    // 20 : Socket system error.
    MMTP_SOCKET_ERROR,
    // 21 : Write buffer full. Use MMTPWriteTerminate to empty it.
    MMTP_BUFFER_FULL,
    // 22 : Pending action to be interrupted does not exist.
    MMTP_NOT_IN_PROGRESS,
    // 23 : Too many listen ports open.
    MMTP_TOO_MUCH_LISTEN_PORTS,
    // 24 : Encryption feature not available.
    MMTP_ENCRYPTION_UNAVAILABLE,
    // 25 : Encryption library invalid.
    MMTP_INVALID_ENCRYPTION_LIB,
    // 26 : System exception trapped.
    MMTP_SYSTEM_EXCEPTION,
    // 27 : System error.
    MMTP_SYSTEM_ERROR,
    // 28 : Bad encryption/decryption key.
    MMTP_BAD_KEY,
    // 29 : The first argument is invalid.
    MMTP_INVALID_ARG1,
    // 30 : The second argument is invalid.
    MMTP_INVALID_ARG2,
    // 31 : The third argument is invalid.
    MMTP_INVALID_ARG3,
    // 32 : The fourth argument is invalid.
    MMTP_INVALID_ARG4,
    // 33 : The fifth argument is invalid.
    MMTP_INVALID_ARG5,
    // 34 : The sixth argument is invalid.
    MMTP_INVALID_ARG6,
    // 35 : The seventh argument is invalid.
    MMTP_INVALID_ARG7,
    // 36 : The eighth argument is invalid.
    MMTP_INVALID_ARG8,
    // 37 : The ninth argument is invalid.
    MMTP_INVALID_ARG9,
    // 38 : No key defined.
    MMTP_NO_KEY_DEFINED,
    // 39 : An exception occurs in an handler.
    MMTP_EXCEPTION_TRAPPED,
    // 40 : Too many waiting sockets defined.
    MMTP_TOO_MANY_WAITING_SOCKETS,
    // 41 : Listen port list invalid.
    MMTP_INVALID_LPL,
    // 42 : Socket error occured during wait. A port is removed.
    MMTP_LPL_SOCKET_ERROR,
    // 43 : The current message does not contains the requested member.
    MMTP_INVALID_MEMBER,
    // 44 : Error in dispatcher managment.
    MMTP_DISPATCHER_ERROR,
    // 45 : The server is unavailable.
    MMTP_SERVER_UNAVAILABLE,
    // 46 : No dispatcher defined.
    MMTP_NO_DISPATCHER_DEFINED,
    // 47 : Dispatcher already defined.
    MMTP_DISPATCHER_ALREADY_DEFINED,
    // 48 : The library is busy.
    MMTP_LIBRARY_BUSY,
    // 49 : Compression error.
    MMTP_COMPRESSION_ERROR,
    // 50 : Invalid administative data.
    MMTP_INVALID_AD,
    // 51 : Exception raised in ModifyMsg user function given using MMTPSetModifyMsgFct API.
    MMTP_MODIFYMSG_FUNCTION_EXCEPTION,

    // Insert new error before this line.
    // Notify the end of the error list.
    MMTP_MAX_NUM_ERROR
  } MMTPError;
```

any one can help me in this process?
any exist c# code or link for get ready code for this struct?
tanks

Comment: We're not here to write code for you.  Any attempt to show? [ask]

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a Union by Explicitly specifying the offset of each item. I'm not sure if a long in your case is 4 or 8 bytes.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct MMTPMsg
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public long length;

    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public short Type;

    [FieldOffset(10)]
    public MMTPConxReq ConxReq;

    [FieldOffset(10)]
    public MMTPConxAck ConxAck;

    [FieldOffset(10)]
    public  MMTPConxNack ConxNack;

    [FieldOffset(10)]
    public MMTPErrInd ErrInd;

    [FieldOffset(10)]
    public MMTPDcnxReq DcnxReq;

    [FieldOffset(10)]
    public  MMTPDcnxAck DcnxAck;

    [FieldOffset(10)]
    public MMTPDataMsg DataMsg;

    [FieldOffset(10)]
    public MMTPSyncAck SyncAck;

    [FieldOffset(10)]
    public  MMTPStartReq StartReq;

    [FieldOffset(10)]
    public MMTPStartAck StartAck;

    [FieldOffset(10)]
    public  MMTPStartNack StartNack;

    [FieldOffset(10)]
    public  MMTPSrvcMsg SrvcMsg;

    [FieldOffset(10)]
    public MMTPDsptchMsg DsptchMsg;

    [FieldOffset(10)]
    public  MMTPRcnxReq RcnxReq;

    [FieldOffset(FIELD_SIZE_OPTIONS+1+8+2)]
    public  Ticks TimeStamp;
}
```